# Does Visual Studio 11 Team Foundation Server Express Beta support Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

If I install [Visual Studio 11 Team Foundation Server Express Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28987), will I be able to use it from a Visual Studio 2010 client?

Comment: The full name is `Visual Studio 11 Team Foundation Server Express Beta`. Note the `Visual Studio 11` that it starts with.

Comment: @Oded I correct my question and I start installing it, whatever it will be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is supported, however you will need to ensure that your Visual Studio 2010 is [kept up-to-date](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/03/23/keeping-your-tfs-2010-up-to-date-as-of-march-2012.aspx).

In particular, you will need to install the [Visual Studio 2010 forward-compatibility pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) in order to connect to a Visual Studio 11 TFS server, or to the TFS service.

Answer (score 2):

In the link you provided there is an additional link: [Visual Studio 11 Team Foundation Server Beta Readme File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=237570). In this file is described a known issue:

> Merging items in unpatched clients may cause item properties to be
>   lost

which is resolved by using as client the Visual Studio 2010. That makes me believe that it is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to use it with VS10.

probably you will need to install Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 11 Beta.

Doenload from here http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28976.